# Dynamic pivot item control Event

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I've create dynamic Pivot item and control with Event.
But my code only active event at last pivot item control

```
public void initPivotItems(int numberOfPivot)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPivot; i++)
    {
        var itemTemplate =
            @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">  
            <StackPanel Margin=""0,0,0,17"" HorizontalAlignment=""Stretch"" Height=""78"" Orientation=""Vertical""> 
                <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Title}"" TextWrapping=""Wrap"" Style=""{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"" Width=""Auto""/>
                <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Description}"" TextWrapping=""Wrap"" Margin=""12,-6,12,0"" Style=""{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"" Width=""Auto""/>
            </StackPanel>  
         </DataTemplate>";


        //Creating Pivot Item
        PivotItem newPiv = new PivotItem();
        newPiv.Header = "Pivot Header"; //defining a header

        //Content for the Pivot Item
        tblRain = new TextBlock();
        tblRain.Text = "Hello " + i;
        tblRain.Tapped += TblRain_Tapped;
        //Adding the list to the Pivot Item
        newPiv.Content = tblRain; //Adding list to Pivot Item
        PivotMyGarden.Items.Add(newPiv); //Adding Pivot Item
    }
}

private void TblRain_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    Debug.WriteLine(tblRain.Text);
}
```

So when i'm test this code , `Debug.WriteLine` only show "**Hello 1**" as soon as i'm in Pivot 0 :(. That's mean the code tblLight.Tapped+= only active for last Pivot Item

How to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the following line in `TblRain_Tapped`:

```
Debug.WriteLine(tblRain.Text);
```

You are using the field `tblRain` which is changed in every for loop iteration, and in the last iteration it is set to your last `TextBlock`.

To `Debug` correctly, use:

```
var tb = sender as TextBlock;
Debug.WriteLine(tb.Text);
```